# How can I make a browser use HTTP header ranges for file downloads during testing?

Tags: python, http, flask, browser, http-headers

I have been searching for this for a while but cannot find any useful answers....

During debugging and testing of a Python backend/JavaScript frontend, I would like to be able to test a browser using HTTP header ranges for file download to validate how my backend logic respond.

When I test locally the browser never use ranges, no matter how big the file is. And yes it does support ranges, I have tested file download with ranges using Postman.

It does not matter which browser I use, any will do.  How do I force or trigger a browser to start using ranges?

EDIT 25/MAY/2023:
I have a Python/Flask flask backend that natively support ranges for file downloads (sendfile). I dont use video only file download. Over time I see a lot of browser range request in my log files, I dont know why and has since been trying to understand.
At each user download I add that info to a history table. Not realizing how ranges were working, I accidently added each range download request into the history table, as if they were separate downloads. Once I realized my mistake I changed the frontend/backend logic to handle this workflow correctly.

Comment: One thing you can do is start a download with firefox, cancel it and then resume. It will use ranges.

Comment: Well how about that, indeed it does, thanks for your help. However I am still puzzled about what logic the browsers are you using to trigger Range requests.

Comment: In what situations do you expect a range request? There's only a few cases where they make sense. Resuming downloads and seeking in videos for example.